# How to reference a Composite Secondary Key

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, composite-key

The below examples show what I tried to **reference an entity by a unique combination of columns that is not its primary key**.

I want to do it that way because the referencing table contains all the necessary constituents of the referenced "Composite Secondary Key" but it does not contain the Primary Key.

**How can I achieve this?** (If possible without being Hibernate specific)

---

## Base example

Suppose an entity has a primary key as well as a composite secondary key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_DATA",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1",
            "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2"})
    })
public class ExampleData {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long exampleDataId;

    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1")
    private String compositeKeyPart1;
    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2")
    private String compositeKeyPart2;
}
```

I would like to reference it from another table by its composite secondary key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE")
public class Example {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long exampleId;

    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1")
    private String compositeKeyPart1; // of ExampleData
    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2")
    private String compositeKeyPart2; // of ExampleData

    @MayToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ExampleData exampleData;
}
```

However, this leads to

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   A Foreign key refering com.example.ExampleData from com.example.Example has the wrong number of column. should be 1

## Making a separate `@Embeddable` composite key

I tried making the secondary key embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1")
    private String compositeKeyPart1;
    @Column(name = "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2")
    private String compositeKeyPart2;
}
```

and using it as an embedded object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_DATA",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_1",
            "COMPOSITE_KEY_PART_2"})
    })
public class ExampleData {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long exampleDataId;

    @Embedded
    private CompositeKey compositeKey;
}
```

but that leads to the same exception:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   A Foreign key refering com.example.ExampleData from com.example.Example has the wrong number of column. should be 1

## Using `@EmbeddedId`

Using `@EmbeddedId` instead of just `@Embedded` leads to issues with multiple keys

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   com.example.CompositeKey must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: com.example.ExampleData.compositeKey

## Having only a single key works but is undesirable

The only way I can actually make it work is by removing the primary key and making the composite key the primary key (but I don't want that)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_DATA")
public class ExampleData {

    // @Id // removing this primary key is undesirable
    @Column
    private Long exampleDataId;

    @EmbeddedId // This now becomes the primary key
    private CompositeKey compositeKey;
}
```

Comment: What's the ID for the Example entity?

Comment: I left it out because I think it doesn't matter; it's ExampleData that has the multiple keys.

Comment: I can obviously see it's  ExampleData with the multiple keys but just wanted however to get a fuller picture as it is not possible to do what  you want.

Comment: I added the `exampleId`. I guess without it, the example was too minimal. Can you elaborate on why it is not possible to have a composite secondary key?